# Laravel 5 - Getting values from collection and passing to view

Tags: php, laravel-5, foreach, laravel-collection

I am building an order management system in Laravel 5.3.
I am storing the orders in two different tables - orders, order_content.
The first one contains order's main data, the other - content. I am using Crinsane's Shopping Cart package for managing order contents. The order contents table fields: identifier, instance, content. Content field contains collection with the specific order content, which is searialized.

My problem is following - i need to get all order contents (product name, code, quantity) in specific date.

This is how far I've gotten:

```
public function showByDate()
{
    $datetime_today = new DateTime('now');
    $date = $datetime_today->format('Y-m-d');

    //get all orders by date, which are confirmed
    $orders = Pasutijums::where('pasutijums_uz', '=', $date)
        ->where('ir_apstiprinats', '=', 1)->get();

    foreach($orders as $order)
    {
        // get order's content
        $order_contents = DB::table('order_content')->where('instance', '=', $order->pasut_num)->get();

        foreach($order_contents as $order)
        {
            // unserialize the content field
            $collection = unserialize($order->content);
        }

    }

    $items = $collection->all();

    return view('admin.kopsavilkumi.pec-datuma')
        ->with('orders', $orders)
        ->with('date', $date)
        ->with('items', $items)
        ;

}
```

In the view I try to loop trough the order contents, but only one product is showing...

```
 @foreach($items as $order)


        <tr>
            <td class="text-primary"> {{ $order->options->code }} </td>
            <td> {{ $order->name }} </td>
            <td> {{ $order->qty }} </td>
        </tr>


@endforeach
```

I need to unserialize each field, save it in collection and pass it to view so i can loop trough them and show them in a table.

UPDATE:
Walter Cejas answer worked for me, but now i need to access the collection's content in my view... This is what I get when dd($collection) in controller:

```
    Collection {#292 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Collection {#307 ▼
        #items: array:2 [▼
        "da951a56dc871db7b48a41f7d14b007b" => CartItem {#308 ▼
            +rowId: "da951a56dc871db7b48a41f7d14b007b"
            +id: "22"
            +qty: "1"
            +name: "Preces nosaukums 1"
            +price: 7.5
            +options: CartItemOptions {#309 ▶}
                -associatedModel: null
                -taxRate: 0
                +"priceTax": 7.5
    }
    "138ba08bdbf1ac8f17e9e6f257af1b88" => CartItem {#310 ▼
                +rowId: "138ba08bdbf1ac8f17e9e6f257af1b88"
                +id: "123"
                +qty: "1"
                +name: "Preces nosaukums 2"
                +price: 1.8
                +options: CartItemOptions {#311 ▶}
                    -associatedModel: null
                    -taxRate: 0
    }
  ]
}
1 => Collection {#306 ▼
                #items: array:1 [▼
                "da951a56dc871db7b48a41f7d14b007b" => CartItem {#312 ▼
                    +rowId: "da951a56dc871db7b48a41f7d14b007b"
                    +id: "22"
                    +qty: "1"
                    +name: "Preces nosaukums 3"
                    +price: 7.5
                    +options: CartItemOptions {#314 ▶}
                        -associatedModel: null
                        -taxRate: 0
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

}

Comment: You're only getting 1 item because you're overwriting `$collection` in your loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I figured that and tried differently saving them in another one, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you're overriding the collection with the last item of the iteration

```
$datetime_today = new DateTime('now');
$date = $datetime_today->format('Y-m-d');

//get all orders by date, which are confirmed
$orders = Pasutijums::where('pasutijums_uz', '=', $date)
    ->where('ir_apstiprinats', '=', 1)->get();
$collection = collect();
foreach($orders as $order)
{
    // get order's content
    $order_contents = DB::table('order_content')->where('instance', '=', $order- 
         >pasut_num)->get();


    foreach($order_contents as $content)
    {
        // unserialize the content field
        $collection->push(unserialize($content));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! But how do I access them in my view now? Updated the question with current output when dd() collection in controller.

Comment: @unity115 If the answer helped, accept and upvote it. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: Great! can you mark my question as answered if it is ! Make a @foreach if you are using blade, also maybe you want to attach a collection of items to every order, in the actual state you're getting all the items in the same collection